# Dynamic button sizing for undefined number of elements

Tags: css

I have a web app that displays an undefined amount of buttons in a large div (where the height is set to `height: calc(100vh - 260px);` and width is `width: 100%`). It can be anywhere between 20-300 buttons in this div. The buttons are always squares with a bit of margin in between each.

I'm currently kind of cheating this by doing this (x, y and z all in pixel values):

```
if buttonCount < 50 {
    height = x
    width = x
} else if buttonCount < 150 {
    height = y
    width = y
} else {
    height = z
    width = z}
```

Where x > y > z. Is there a way to dynamically size the undefined amount of buttons so that they're an equal size and fit within the div?

Comment: Do *what* exactly? The code is useful but a bit of explanation as to your actual end-goal might be a bit more helpful. Do `x`, `y`, and `z` get smaller? Bigger? The full width of the page? Without being able to see or understand the actual rendered view, nor the values of the variables, it's difficult to provide CSS.

Comment: You mean you want all the buttons to fit on one row, fill the entire row, and remain square?

Comment: @TylerRoper edited the question to hopefully provide more clarity

Comment: @showdev I'd like all the buttons to fit within a div element and have it scale accordingly to the # of buttons

Comment: "Fit within a div element" isn't very clear. By default, `<div>` elements expand to fit their content, so unless you write code to specifically do otherwise, a `<div>` will *always* fit the buttons. It's still not clear what you're asking.